# Linux: How to not limit output from top based on screen width

Tags: linux

EDIT:  I was chastised for being off subject.  I edited out the file method I used as an example and inserted C++ method from reality.

I am using C++ popen to issue a *top* command to get system information into my program, then into an xml file I can send off-system.  I parse the output of top into various variables (painful bit of code) which get poled into the xml.

*top* very helpfully truncates it's output's width to fit on the screen even in batch mode where the output is redirected to a pipe.

```
popen( "top -b -n 1", "r" );
```

Works the same if the output is sent to a file.

Is there a way to tell top to show all its fields (in batch mode) even if they would fall off the right side of the screen?

NOTE:  In my particular case, I ran my c++ top-parser on my  workstation and got, say, 15 columns per PID.  Then I changed to fewer characters in the line (bigger text).  I completely lost the 15th field.  Then I tried an in-between font and got all but one column of the 15th field back.  That field ends in %st and I count on it saying that, not %s.  Fixing this need to be generic, not based on individual cases.

Thanks for the help.  I checked Google and it knows much about top, but just how to ask.....

NB:  If you'd like to see this phenomenon, run top in your usual command window capturing the output to a file or pipe, then change the font in the window to have more characters on each line of the terminal window and rerun the command.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `ps`?

Comment: Because the boss asked for the output of *top* to be passed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `COLUMNS` environment variable:

```
$ COLUMNS=10000 top
```

Comment: Great idea.  Put lots of extra space on the end of the on-screen lines (I used 1000, not 10000, thank God).  Sadly, it didn't make it into the file.  Almost like I need to set **COLUMNS=1000 >** except, of course, you can't co that, at least not using that syntax.

Comment: My error.  This did work when I realized that a pipe might actually work differently than a file.  Change the code to read, popen( "export COLUMNS=100; top -b -n 1", "r" );