# Truncated result when using Paramiko invoke_shell

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using Paramiko `invoke_shell` to pull results of the `top` command from a remote system. But I am getting truncated lines when looking at the results.

Code as follows :

```
channel = token.invoke_shell()

channel.send ('terminal length 0\n')
time.sleep(1)
resp = channel.recv(9999)
output = resp.decode('ascii')

channel.send('top -n 1\n')
time.sleep(1)
resp = channel.recv(9999)
output = resp.decode('ascii')
result = (''.join(output))

return (result)
```

The result is as follows (note `cn_node+` is not the complete name, it is longer):

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  28639 root      20   0   17.0g  38912  28336 S 111.1   0.1   1101:49 cn-node+
  29889 root      20   0 3379668  16532  13428 S  94.4   0.1 991:39.71 Flare
```

If directly ssh'ed into the system and running the command, the result is :

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  28639 root      20   0   17.0g  38912  28336 S 116.7   0.1   1186:17 cn-node-cnfp
  29889 root      20   0 3379668  16796  13428 S  94.4   0.1   1067:53 Flare
```

Wondering how to get the whole line and not the truncated line (get `cn-node-cnfp` instead of `cn-node+`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `width` parameter of [`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) to more than the default value of `80`:

```
channel = token.invoke_shell(width=160)
```

---

Though better is probably to use `COLUMN` environment variable.

See [Linux: How to not limit output from top based on screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11669768/850848)

---

In any case, you in general should not use `SSHClient.invoke_shell` for automating command execution. Use `SSHClient.exec_command. See [What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)